# SQL - Ordering second column based on the first column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to retrieve data from a table, but I need it to be ordered in a very specific way and I'm not sure if it's possible using Oracle SQL alone.

What I need to do is retrieve all of the rows, but order it in a way that where column 3 is null (indicated by a blank space in the graphs below) those are ordered first. Then, all the rows that aren't null in column 3 would be shown AFTER the row that has their column value in column 1.

What I have:

```
+------+-------+------+
| Col1 | Col2  | Col3 |
+------+-------+------+
|    1 | text  |      |
|    2 | text  |    1 |
|    3 | text  |    1 |
|    8 | text  |   10 |
|    9 | text  |   10 |
|   10 | text  |      |
+------+-------+------+
```

What I would like as a result:

```
+------+-------+------+
| Col1 | Col2  | Col3 |
+------+-------+------+
|    1 | text  |      |
|    2 | text  |    1 |
|    3 | text  |    1 |
|   10 | text  |      |
|    8 | text  |   10 |
|    9 | text  |   10 |
+------+-------+------+
```

What I have tried:

First thing I tried was using:

```
ORDER BY coalesce(Col3, Col1)
```

and it got me close to the result, but the Col1 value 10 needs to be shown before the Col3 value 10.

```
+------+-------+------+
| Col1 | Col2  | Col3 |
+------+-------+------+
|    1 | text  |      |
|    2 | text  |    1 |
|    3 | text  |    1 |
|    8 | text  |   10 |
|    9 | text  |   10 |
|   10 | text  |      |
+------+-------+------+
```

I've also tried creating a new column where if Col3 is null then Col4 is true and false other wise, but this was essentially the same thing as coalesce up above.

I also tried just running some basic order by's but had no success in achieving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you would just use `nulls first`:

```
order by coalesce(col3, col1), col3 nulls first, col1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table looks very much like hierarchical data, where in some sense `col1` is a unique row identifier, and `col3` points to a row's parent row.

If so, it may be better to use a hierarchical query (`connect by`) for this. The ordering is hierarchical, and siblings (descendants from the same parent) are ordered according to the `order siblings by` clause.

Like this:

```
with
  sample_table(col1, col2, col3) as (
    select  1, 'text', null from dual union all     
    select  2, 'text',    1 from dual union all
    select  3, 'text',    1 from dual union all
    select  8, 'text',   10 from dual union all
    select  9, 'text',   10 from dual union all
    select 10, 'text', null from dual
  )
select  *
from    sample_table
start   with col3 is null
connect by col3 = prior col1
order   siblings by col1
;

      COL1 COL2       COL3
---------- ---- ----------
         1 text           
         2 text          1
         3 text          1
        10 text           
         8 text         10
         9 text         10
```

The `with` clause is not part of the solution - I added it there so I can test the query. (Remember this "`with` clause" way to create sample tables for testing - you can include them yourself, instead of the formatted table in your original question, so that people can easily test their answers on your sample data.)

Comment: Is there a way that I could add a where clause that says "where Col1 = 10" to get the last three rows (COL1 = {10, 8, 9})? 
Solved my own question by just adding and AND to the "start with". Thank you! This actually solved another issue I was having.

Comment: @stackiee - Most likely, that should go in the `start with` clause, not the `where` clause. Try `start with col1 = 10` - see if that answers your question.